# ООП в Java, принципы

Tags: java, ооп, классы

В Java приложении есть класс `World`, где создаются объекты игры `ArrayList` с доступом `public`. Есть также класс `Player`. Объекты класса `Player` создаются в конструкторе класса `World`.

В чём собственно проблема:
Из объекта класса `Player` не доступны поля `ArrayLists` объекта `World`. 
P.S.: Код исправлен. Теперь из объекта класса Player доступны поля класса World.

```
 public class GameScreen extends Screen{
        enum GameState{
            Running,
            Paused,
            GameOver
        }

        GameState state = GameState.Running;
        World world;
        Player CPU;
        Player human;
        public int j = 0;

        public GameScreen(Game game)
        {
            super(game);
            world = new World();
            CPU = new Player(true, world);
            human = new Player(false, world);
            for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)// раздаём карты
            {
                Card c = world.deck.dealCard();
                Card c1 = world.deck.dealCard();
                CPU.takeCard(c);
                human.takeCard(c1);
            }
            human.hand.sortByValue();// сортируем карты
            CPU.hand.sortByValue();
            Card c = CPU.hand.getCard(1);// ПК сделал ход
            CPU.hand.removeCard(1);
            world.cpuCards.add(c);
        }
}

public class World {
public Deck deck;
public boolean gameOver = false;

public ArrayList<Card> cpuCards;// карты ПК на столе
public ArrayList<Card> humanCards;// карты игрока на столе

public World()
{
    deck = new Deck();
    deck.shuffle();
    cpuCards = new ArrayList<>();
    humanCards = new ArrayList<>();

}

public class Player {
    public boolean AI; // Игрок ИИ || человек?

    public Hand hand;
    public int trump;
    World world;
    public ArrayList<Card> cpuCards;// карты ПК на столе
    public ArrayList<Card> humanCards;// карты игрока на столе

    public Player(boolean AI, World world)
    {
        hand = new Hand();
        this.AI = AI;
        cpuCards = world.cpuCards;
        humanCards = world.humanCards;
    }
```

Comment: А в чём заключается ваш вопрос? Добавте в вопрос ваш код.

Answer (score 1):

> Из объекта класса Player не доступны поля ArrayLists объекта World.

Потому, что у класса Player нет полей для обращения к World. Тут вопрос в том, кому принадлежать колоды карт. По логике они принадлежать игрокам, а не миру, поэтому и владеть ими должны игроки.

Вы можете создавать их в классе World, а при создании объекта Person передавать ему его колоду.

```
    CPU = new Player(true, cpuCards);
    human = new Player(false, humanCards);
```

И тогда вам не придется лезть в чужой класс за вашими данными.

---

И второй момент, заметил, что у вас `boolean AI` статична, а значит она принадлежит не объектам, а классу. По вашей логике, лучше сделать её нестатической.

Статические переменные имеют 1 экземпляр на все классы. Создавая первого person вы присваиваете ей значение `true`, создавая второго `false` и в итоге у обоих игроков `AI = false;`